# Getting all the test cases inside the test folder using Pyral api

Tags: python, rest, pyral

I have used pyral api

```
rally = Rally(server, apikey=api_key, workspace=workspace, project=project)
```

to connect to rally
Than ,

```
  testfolders = rally.get('TestFolder', fetch=True, query=query_criteria)
```

I need to extract all the test cases defined in the rally as:

```
TF*****
  -TC1
  -TC2
  -TC3
```

I need to get all the test cases from the formattedID returned from 
testfolders.

```
for tc in testfolders:
   print(tc.Name)
   print(tc.FormattedID)# this represents the TF***
   tc_link=tc._ref#url for TC's https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice
```

```
query_criteria = 'TestSets = "%s"' % tp_name
testfolders = rally.get('TestFolder', fetch=True, query=query_criteria)
```

I have tried looking for different combination sets to extract test cases 
The tc._ref is actually a

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestFolder/XXXXX/TestCases
```

when I tried to open it in browser it gave the entire Test cases list.
I need to extract those test case list .
I tried accessing using urllib to acess the data using python ,but said unauthorized access, I think if I am on the same session authorization shouldnt be an issue since rally object is already instantiated.
Any help on this will be much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance

```
    rally = Rally(server, apikey=api_key, workspace=workspace, project=project)
    tp_name = "specific test case "
    query_criteria = 'FormattedID = "%s"' % tp_name
    testfolders = rally.get('TestFolder', fetch=True, query=query_criteria)
    for tc in testfolders:
         print(tc.Name)
         print(tc.FormattedID)   
         query_criteria = 'TestSets = "%s"' % tc._ref
         response = rally.get('TestCase', fetch=True, query=query_criteria)
         print(response)
```

```
422 Could not read: could not read all instances of class com.f4tech.slm.domain.TestCase for class TestCase
```

Comment: Please take a look at answer below and accept if it work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve but please take a look at the code below. Probably, it will solve your issue:

```
query = 'FormattedID = %s'

test_folder_req = rally.get('TestFolder', fetch=True, projectScopeDown=True,
                                       query=query % folder_id) # folder_id == "TF111"
if test_folder_req.resultCount == 0:
    print('Rally returned nothing for folder: %s', folder_id)
    sys.exit(1)

test_folder = test_folder_req.next()

test_cases = test_folder.TestCases
print('Start working with %s' % folder_id)
print('Test Folder %s contains %s TestCases' % (folder_id, len(test_cases)))

for test_case in test_cases:
    print(test_case.FormattedID)
    print(test_case.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks **@user2738882** ,it helped me . Suppose for example the folder structure in rally is like. How can we go about this .Thanks in advance .I need to extract all test case ids
**-Track1
    -module 1
         -TF1
              -TC1
              -TC2
         -TF1
              -TC1
              -TC2
-module 2
       -module 1
         -TF1
              -TC1
              -TC2
         -TF1
              -TC1**

Comment: That's super easy you need just to iterate through binary tree to find all leaves. You have everything for it.